# ASP.Net Sharing resources between cultures

Tags: asp.net

If I have a multi-language app that supports en-UK and en-US in resx files all is fine and the eg. the txtColour key resolves to "Colour" or "Color" in the correct case.

Even though the majority of language is shared between these two, it appears that I would need to maintain two resx's to get just the few differences - is this true?

Answer (score 0):

After some tests it appears that I can have a en-US resource with all text, then en-UK with just the differences. If a value is not found in en-UK.resx then it will search up the chain and use the value from en-US so all is ok.

The only gotcha is appears to be that the 'default' resx used by <%$Resources:ads.language,test%> must contain all the keys else compilation errors occur.
From this is would make sense to have eg. ads.language.resx (defaults to en-US & has all keys, then ads.language.en-UK for the UK-specific bits.